# Do we need a transmit and a receive filter in a OFDM transceiver system?

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications, ofdm, digital-filters

can anyone specify in brief what are the filters that can be used as a transmit and receive filter in OFDM. Any material to start with will be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What material did you read on OFDM so far? This feels like you don't have a good textbook.

Comment: the above is a really short answer, because the asker there was using OFDM for quite a while, so it was fair to assume they knew all the reasons cyclic-prefix-OFDM is done like it's done. You don't seem to have that knowledge yet – an answer here would really require writing down a complete introduction to OFDM, which any textbook really does better than I could do it here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have read about OFDM and I am asking this question with respect to simulation. I know the concepts of cyclic prefix and all. I am asking this because if I want to use a DUC and a DDC for achieving up conversion and down conversion, do I have to introduce transmit and receive filtering as well? Because the cyclic prefix takes care of the ISI so I thought is it necessary to do filtering here. I would be happy though if you want me to read a better reference.

Comment: @MarcusMüller My question is also due to the fact that OFDM system is basically a transmultiplexer and can be considered as a system which does filterbank operation

Comment: You will need interpolation filters for a higher sample rate if you want to mix up your signal, yes, but that has nothing to do with OFDM contained within; ideally, these filters have no shape that you see within your baseband.